# XML element containing other xml characters replaced using xstream

Tags: xml, xstream

I'm using xstream in java 1.4 and I'm having an issue with some embedded xml in the elements.

I have the following message:

```
<detail>
<SwiftMessage><SWIFT>hi<SWIFT/><SwiftMessage/>
<detail/>
```

The element data hi is a string held in the SwiftMessage tags. I can see that Xstream is seeing these and replacing them with

```
&lt;SWIFT&gt;hi&lt;SWIFT/&gt;
```

otherwise it creates invalid xml. What I want to know is there any way to quote this string to prevent xstream from doing this. Its part of a JMS message that is being sent to another system and they won't like the replacements.

Much appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 2):

As James pointed out, your embedded XML is not properly closed, but the main point: any XML-API must escape embedded XML to prevent structural changes to the XML format, i.e. the embedded XML is and must be interpreted as a simple text node to prevent 'XML injection'.

If I understand correctly, the cause of the problem is that the send and receive processes are not symmetric: you `send( XStream.toXML( JMS.xml() ) )` and then `receive( JMS.xml() )`.
If you change your receive procedure to `receive( XStream.fromXML( JMS.xml() ) )` then the `XStream.fromXML()` will parse the XML, reverting the embedded XML from 'escaped' to 'original'.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a genuine example of your XML? Your tag closing is wrong

```
<detail>
<SwiftMessage><SWIFT>hi<SWIFT/><SwiftMessage/>
<detail/>
```

It should be:

```
<detail>
<SwiftMessage><SWIFT>hi</SWIFT></SwiftMessage>
</detail>
```

A backslash at the end of an element name signifies that the element is empty, like an html br tag: `<br/>`

So your XML is saying: Open detail tag, open SwiftMessage tag, open SWIFT tag, text hi, add empty SWIFT tag, add empty SwiftMessage tag, add empty detail tag. The tags aren't actually being closed.

I assume the receiving application is expecting the SWIFT element as valid XML, rather than a string? You may need to show how you add the SWIFT element. If you feed it into the value of the SwiftMessage element it will likely be interpreted as a string value, with your XML processor automatically replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;` as these characters are reserved for constructing elements.

Otherwise, if you want the SWIFT element to be regarded as a string value then you need to use a CDATA section.